# How to add background images in TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to add background images to my training data. I am using TensorFlow 1.4. I am trying to add these files directly to images directory and the CSV file train_labels.csv. However I am getting errors when I run both: faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco.config & ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config. My train_labels.csv has the following fields:

**filename,width,height,class,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax**

For a background image the corresponding input is:
**pattern.jpg,200,200,background,,,,**

I have tried:

```
python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config

And got the error: **tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: All bounding box coordinates must be in [0.0, 1.0]: nan**

I have also tried python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco.config

INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 33.
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34: loss = 0.7557 (24.100 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 35: loss = 0.7095 (15.436 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 36: loss = 1.4553 (16.423 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 37: loss = 1.1022 (15.649 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class **'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, LossTensor is inf or nan. : Tensor had NaN values
[[Node: CheckNumerics = CheckNumericsT=DT_FLOAT, message="LossTensor is inf or nan.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]**
```

Bot the fast-rcnn and ssd work fine if I remove the background images from the CSV file as well as the images directory. For my background images I am just using a image which is totally white as that is the background in all my training images. I am quite sure I am not entering the background images correctly. How do I go about this?

Comment: Did you fix this issue, If yes can you please guide me to successfully add background images, train it and apply prediction. Thank you..